# How to center subplot on timeline with limited y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I've got some code used to generate an event timeline, but I'd like to add in an additional line plot showing quantity sold on each day. But when I run the plot, the timeline gets compressed and the Y-axis expands to the new plot. The only way to get around this issue is to normalize the quantity plot values which seems to fit the y-axis limits of the timeline plot, but ideally I'd like to keep the original values from the line plot in the first picture and get it working with the timeline plot from the second picture, so it's the original values and centered/scaled properly. The data is just formatted as a text file like this: Date,Event \n 12 July 2021, Event 1

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd


def GenerateTimeLine2(data, data02, title="Timeline", xaxis_format="%d %b", day_interval=5, figsize=(8, 5)):
    levels = np.array([-5, 5, -3, 3, -1, 1])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    # Create the base line
    start = min(data.index)
    stop = max(data.index)
    ax.plot((start, stop), (0, 0), 'k', alpha=.5)
    # Iterate through data annoting each one
    for ii, (idate, iname) in enumerate(data.itertuples()):
        level = levels[ii % 6]
        vert = 'top' if level < 0 else 'bottom'

        ax.scatter(idate, 0, s=100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k', zorder=9999)
        # Plot a line up to the text
        ax.plot((idate, idate), (0, level), c='r', alpha=.7)
        # Give the text a faint background and align it properly
        ax.text(idate, level, iname,ha='right', va=vert, fontsize=14,
                backgroundcolor=(1., 1., 1., .3))
        
    ax.set(title=title)
    # Set the xticks formatting
    # format xaxis with days intervals
    ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=day_interval))
    ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(xaxis_format))
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    #add in overlay line plot
    #ax.plot(data02)
    #print(ax.axis())
    #min_c = min(data02.values.tolist())
    #max_c = max(data02.values.tolist())
    #ax.set_ylabel(min_c,max_c)
    norm = lambda x: 5*(x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())
    ax.set_yticks(norm(data02.values))
    #((data02.values-(min(data02.values.tolist())))/(max(data02.values.tolist())-min(data02.values.tolist()))))
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))
    ax.axes.set_ylabel('Quanitity')
    ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
    ax.plot(norm(data02))
    #ax.plot((min_c,max_c), (0, 0), 'k', alpha=.5)
    #print(ax.yaxis)
    # Remove components for a cleaner look
    plt.setp((list(ax.spines.values())), visible=False)#ax.get_yticklabels() + 
    
    return ax

data = pd.read_csv(r'testdata01.txt', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
data02 = pd.read_csv(r'rap_a.txt', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
ax = GenerateTimeLine2(data,data02,title='Event Timeline',
                       day_interval=1,figsize=(8,5))
#ax.patch.set_facecolor('gray')
#ax.plot(data02)
plt.show()
```

[image: Line plot with correct scale]
[image: Line plot with normalized values and centered timeline]

Comment: Please consider making your example as minimal as possible and making it self constrained.

Comment: Due to the strangeness that comes from the timeline plot shape, self constraint doesn't quite work it seems

Comment: Sorry typo:  self-contained.